# Cef Cookie Manager SetCookie always returns false

Tags: c++, visual-studio, curl, webview, chromium-embedded

I am doing a project where I load a webview in my application(using visual studio 2012). On before loading web view i send a curl request to get some access_token which i need to set in the cookie for that particular webview so that the user is signed in for that webview automatically. So in the callback from curl when i get the token i call  **setCookie** on **cef global cookie Manager** but it always returns me **false**.

```
CefRefPtr<CefCookieManager> cookieManager=CefCookieManager::GetGlobalManager();
    CefString cefURL ;
    cefURL.FromString(url.GetUTF8String());
    bool retVal = cookieManager->SetCookie(cefURL,cookie);
```

Am i doing something wrong, is it because i am doing it on the curl callback which is a seperate thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
CefRefPtr<CefCookieManager> manager =
        CefCookieManager::GetGlobalManager(nullptr);
DCHECK(manager.get());
CefCookie cookie;
        CefString(&cookie.name).FromString(key);
        CefString(&cookie.value).FromString(value);
        CefString(&cookie.domain).FromString(domain);
        CefString(&cookie.path).FromString("/");
        cookie.has_expires = true;
        cookie.expires.year = 2099;
        cookie.expires.month = 1;
        cookie.expires.day_of_week = 1;
        cookie.expires.day_of_month = 1;
        std::string url = "https://" + domain;//eg:".stackoverflow.com"
        //manager->SetCookie(url, cookie, nullptr);
        CefPostTask(TID_IO, NewCefRunnableMethod(manager.get()
            , &CefCookieManager::SetCookie
            , CefString(url.c_str()), cookie, nullptr));
```

Set up through interprocess communication，use CefPostTask function

Comment: Might be worth adding an short explanation of _why_ this works when the OP's code doesn't

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Older versions required cookies be set on the IO thread. Newer versions that have a callback as a parameter can be called on any thread. IPC is not relevant